# How to pass JSON to controller action?

Tags: asp.net, json

I have some textboxes and a table of data created client side that I want pass to a controller as JSON.

Can you please give me the syntax for this?
I want to use Jquery to enumerate the table.

Assume I have 2 textboxes called name and age.
Assume a table with 2 columns. one column with class
called phonetype and one column class called phonenumber.

So how do construct the JSON from this?

Thanks in advance.

Malcolm

Answer (score 0):

Sending Json to a ActionResult with an object as the parameter and using the [JsonValueProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonvalueproviderfactory%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) do the deserialization.

[Sending JSON to an ASP.NET MVC Action Method Argument](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx)

Looping through table rows:

```
 var tableRows = $('.TableDemo tr');
 tableRows.each(function () {
     var tdText = $(this).find('#id_of_td_with_data').text();

 });
```

Comment: I am having trouble with the syntax using jquery to enumerate the table and how to construct the json string.